# Hibernate inserts duplicate parent entry with on oneToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, duplicates

I have two classes, Upload and Filter. Upload is the "parent" and can have n Filters, but a Filter can only belong to one Upload. --> oneToMany

When my rest api gets called it creates an upload with an empty list of filters.
After saving, it creates TWO entries for upload with different PK but same values for no obvious reason!

This is very frustrating since im out of keywords that i can throw at this stupid framework to make it work.

What could be the issue here?

**Code that persists:**

```
session.getTransaction().begin();
Upload upload = new Upload();
upload.setFiltering(new ArrayList<Filter>()); //empty list
session.save(upload);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

**Upload.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "upload")
public class Upload {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "upload", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private java.util.List<Filter> filtering;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
```

**Filter.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "filter")
public class Filter {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "upload_id")
    private Upload upload;
```

Comment: Just a remark : `upload.setFiltering(new ArrayList<Filter>());` won't change anything, because the `Upload`-`Filter` relationship is configured on the `Filter` side (due to the `mappedBy` attribute on the `Upload` side)

Comment: Try changing filtering to Set<Filter>; you can also try adding cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} to your ManyToOne and OnetoMany annotation.